# Can php session variable be changed, and if so how?

Tags: php, session-variables

I am totally confused with session variables. I thought that if I set a session variable, then that variable will be available in any php document that begins with session_start. But it's not working.

Form:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['hour'])) {
$_SESSION['hour'] = $_POST['hour'];
} 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action='viewA.php' method='post'>
 <input type="text" name='hour' value='24'>
 <input type ='submit' name= 'submit' value='submit'>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I post to `viewA.php`, and it works:

```
<?php
$hour = $_POST['hour'];
echo 'I am view A, and hour is '.$hour;

?>
<html>
<a href='View_B.php'>See View B</a>
<a href='TEST_form.php' >Choose another hour</a>
</html>
```

The file `viewA.php` has a link to View_B.php; here's View_B's code:

```
<?php
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
//$hour = $_SESSION['hour'];
//echo '... and in view B, hour is '.$hour;
?>
<html>
<a href='aatestform.php' >Choose another hour</a>
</html>
```

No matter what I put into the input in the form, the `print_r($_SESSION);` View_B outputs only `Array ( [hour] => 13 )`, which is the first hour I chose way back when. I type in "22"; it outputs 13. I type in "08", it outputs 13.

According to w3schools, "[To change a session variable, just overwrite it](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)"

What am I doing wrong? Please help!

Comment: can you turn on error_reporting(E_ALL) and see if there is a "can't overwrite headers" error?

Comment: When you post the form to `ViewA.php`, it will execute `ViewA.php` so the PHP part in your form won't be evaluated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `viewA.php` you don't store / overwrite the session variable with the `$_POST` value.

You just do it in your `TEST_form.php` which doesn't get any `$_POST` so your `if(isset(...` is useless.

Comment: ah yes, that was it... $_SESSION['hour'] = $_POST['hour']; belongs in viewA.php -- MANY THANKS! this was driving me crazy

Answer (score 1):

Your post destination (the action) is `viewA.php`, this means that your request will be made to `viewA.php`.

You're using session variabiles **only** in the `form` page and in `View_B.php`.

If you look carefully at your code in `ViewA.php`, you'll see that you're working only with `POST` variables, not session variables.

This php code, that you have in your `form` page

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['hour'])) {
$_SESSION['hour'] = $_POST['hour'];
} 
?>
```

Should be moved to `viewA.php`.
Doing this, `viewA.php` will check if the POST variable "hours" is set. In that case, it overwrite (or create) the session variable "hours".

Comment: yes, done, and it works.  Thanks so much for your answer.